# Windows 7 vs. XP GetIsNetworkAvailable() difference?

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I wrote code to populate a menu with the available IPv4 NICards on a machine.  It has been tested on an XP machine and it seems all fine and well (it was also built on XP).

I had it tested on Windows 7 and it always populated 2 IP address even if one was disconnected.  Here are the results for the Win7 machine:

**WLAN Connected 

LAN  Disconnected** 
Observed: Correct WLAN address shows, Incorrect LAN address shows (it is even a different network number where it's connected to 192.168 however the LAN address that is populated in the menu is 169.254)
Expected: Correct WLAN address shows, No LAN shows (it is disconnected)
ipconfig reads "Media disconnected" for LAN

**WLAN Connected 

LAN  Connected** 
Observed: Correct WLAN address shows, Correct LAN address shows
Expected: Correct WLAN address shows, Correct LAN address shows
ipconfig reads correct address

**WLAN Disconnected 

LAN  Connected** 
Observed: Correct WLAN address shows, Correct LAN address shows
Expected: No WLAN address shows(it is disconnected), Correct LAN shows
ipconfig reads "Media disconnected" for WLAN

Here is the code block:

```
_adapters.Clear();
if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
    NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in networkInterfaces)
    {
        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation addr in adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
        {
            //This filters out IPv6 and Loopback NICs
            if (addr.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork
                && adapter.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback) 
            {    //This formats something like: 192.168.1.0 - Ethernet adapter Local Network Connection
                _adapters.Add(addr.Address.ToString() + " - " + adapter.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString() + " adapter " + adapter.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using 4.0 .NET on VS2010 for what its worth

Comment: Title seems a bit odd, since the question doesn't really relate to `GetIsNetworkAvailable`, does it?

Comment: Well `GetIsNetworkAvailable()` get's all the interfaces where a network connection is available. Isn't it intuitive to think a network connection isn't available if it reads "Media Disconnected" in ipconfig? Maybe it should've been written 'GetIsNetworkCardAvailable()' but that isn't up to me, sorry.

Comment: `GetIsNetworkAvailable()` returns a boolean - it says whether any network *is* available. All of your examples listed situations where *at least one* network was available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if a NIC is connected or not you should check the `NetworkInterface.OperationalStatus` property.

The "strange" IP address when LAN is disconnected comes from APIPA (Automatic Private IP Addressing). A "feature" introduced with Windows Vista:

> ...a feature in Windows Vista to automatically configure itself with an IP address and subnet mask when a DHCP server isn't available. The IP address range is 169.254.0.1 through 169.254.255.254, a range that has been reserved especially for Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft uses the term APIPA, but the use 169.254.0.0/16 in IPV4 and fe80::/64 in IPV6 is more generically called a link-local address. (MS was one of the authors of the original RFC, but it's a stretch to say that the range was "reserved especially for" them. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3927). Also, link-local was supported in Win 98, according to the RFC.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The question of which is better to do now: use `NetworkInterface.OperationalStatus` or parse out and exclude 169.254 addresses--or are they interchangeable?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling it was a quote from TechNet...they're little bit...self-centric! LOL

Comment: @klut 169.254.x.x could even be a valid address (simply without a DHCP) but operational (it doesn't really mean that the NIC is **disconnected**).

Comment: @Adriano: Ah, I was curious where you got it from.