# Clarification on code

Tags: c#, network-programming, ip-address, network-protocols

I'm looking at code, and I'm not certain of its functionality.  I looked at documentation for the functions however they didn't do much justice.  Here is the code:

```
    private void m_InitUdpSock()
    {
        m_sockBroadcast = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        m_sockBroadcast.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast,1);

        m_localhost     = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(m_localHostIP),BIND_PORT);
        m_remotehost    = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast,SCAN_PORT);

        m_sockBroadcast.Bind(m_localhost);
        m_sockBroadcast.BeginReceiveFrom(m_rxBuffer,0,m_rxBuffer.Length,SocketFlags.None,ref m_HostEp,new AsyncCallback(ReceiveBroadcastData),m_sockBroadcast);
    }
```

From what I understand: this function is setting up a socket to broadcast a UDP message.  It is using the `m_localhost` to send out broadcast.  The `m_localhost` **used** to be:

```
m_localhost     = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,BIND_PORT);
```

Then, I wanted to [select the Network Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035230/windows-7-vs-xp-getisnetworkavailable-difference) I chose to communicate with, so I retrieved IP address of the Network Adapter I wanted to use and changed the `m_localhost` to the first example.  Then using the `Bind` function, it should use the specificed network adapter, and use the port, `BIND_PORT`, to listen to respoonse messages.

I'm hoping someone could confirm I'm indeed using the network adapter of the IP I pass localhost.

The `m_remotehost` is just a `IPEndPoint`, which will hold an IP Address of a packet that responds, and the port, `SCAN_PORT`, with be the outgoing broadcast port.

`SCAN_PORT` and `BIND_PORT` have comments from previous developer; however I don't know that they are accurate.  Is m_remotehost specifying the port it should use to communicate back with me? *(That sounds like bad practice to me)*

```
SCAN_PORT  // Outgoing broadcast port.
BIND_PORT  // Incoming response listen port.
```

Next, in `BeginReceiveFrom`, the documentation was clear for the most part, however the parameter the previous developer used "ref HostEp" threw me off, because it was declared as:

```
m_HostEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,0);
```

so when I call `BeginReceiveFrom`, is it still using any local IP Address to broadcast messages, which is not what I want?  `m_HostEp` is also used in the call `EndReceiveFrom(iar,ref m_HostEp)`.

I'm looking for clarification on:
1. `BIND_PORT` and `SCAN_PORT`
2. What is `m_HostEp` usage, how is it affecting my communication?

If you need any clarifications, ask!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code snippet, `m_remotehost` is not used so you cannot determine the meaning of  `SCAN_PORT` from it, but apparently the broadcast messages can be sent on a different port than the one incoming messages are received on.

- `BIND_PORT` is the port you will receive messages on.
- `m_HostEp` will contain the `EndPoint` of the sender of the message you receive.

When learning about sockets I read http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/ which turned out to be a great reference if you want to know more about the things "under the hood" as broadcast networking can be tricky. It isn't targetted specifically to c# though.

Comment: `m_remotehost` is used here: `m_sockBroadcast.SendTo(yCmdScan, m_remotehost);` Does that help?

Comment: `SCAN_PORT` should then be the port the broadcast messages are sent to.

Comment: You're right!  I tried it and at first I was getting an error, but I increased the buffer size and I'm receiving perfectly.  

Just curious, is there a way to send out a packet to a port, and determine if the port I'm trying to broadcast to is unable to be opened.  If it was open I would be able to tell my user that its in use then.

Comment: You'll only get an exception if you try to bind (listen) on a port that is already in use (so `m_sockBroadcast.Bind(m_localhost);` would fail if BIND_PORT was already in use).